# How can I run different codes from different editor tabs on the Spyder on the same console (as opposed to different tabs)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, editor, spyder

I have few different codes and routines open on my spyder and each of them that I run, a new console tab opens that exclusively belongs to that certain code, while I  prefer to have the same console. One reason is that I want the variables to work in all the conosoles to try different things on the console without having to introduce a variable in each tab separately.
I believe that the default of Spyder is only one console but I think I have done something wrong so it has now as many consoles tabs as editors tabs.

cheers
Travis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferences > Run > Execute in current console
[image: Screen Grab]

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl + F6` to bring up `Configuration per file` under `Run` in top bar.

Under Console,

[image: sss]